# Django - Batch Actions in a ListView - Select Rows and Return a Zip Archive in Response

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, php-ziparchive

Ok, first off, I know this is not the best way to handle serving files on a prod server.
But this site will be accessed by a small group of users, the request for these files
should be minimal, and the static files being served are very small -  so I am trying to keep things simple.

I have a ListView Table where the user can select rows and then perform batch actions on the objects (eg. Delete, Export CSVs, Send CSV data to another location, etc). I've created a class based view to handle each of these batch actions. The only action that I can't get to work is when the user requests a download of a ZIP archive of the CSV data.

When the ZIP export action is selected from the ListView, the selected rows are written as individual CSV files into to a static file location, and then zipped into a single ZIP archive. But the FileResponse never returns the archive to the user as a download.

I've tried different ways of handling the response - redirecting to a new URL,
reverse to the ListView, different URL patterns, etc.

the method shown below that handles the create and zip of the CSV is called: `batch_csv_zip`

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong. thanks.

```
class BatchActionView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, TemplateView):
    """
    Takes a list of pks to perform a batch action
    """
    model = SlateDoc
    template_name = 'slatedoc_batch_action.html'
    
    permission_required = ('slatedoc.can_run_batch_actions')
    permission_denied_message = "Permission Denied"


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if not request.user.has_perm(permission_required):
            messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        else:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
 
        if request.method == 'POST':
            input = request.POST.get('inputString')
            input_dict = eval(input)
            modalID = input_dict["modalID"]
            pkList = input_dict["pks"].split(",")
            self.batch_actions(request, modalID, pkList)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


    def get_success_url(self):
        input = self.request.POST.get('inputString')
        input_dict = eval(input)
        modalID = input_dict["modalID"]
        pks = input_dict["pks"]

        if modalID == "csvModalSubmit":
            return reverse_lazy('slatedoc-list')
            # return reverse('batch-actions')
            # return reverse('slatedoc-download', kwargs={'pks': pks})
            # return reverse('slatedoc-download', kwargs={'file': f"{zipfilename}.zip"})

        else:
            return reverse_lazy('slatedoc-list')


    def batch_actions(self, request, modalID, pkList):
        """
        Check the modalID data from POST to trigger a Batch Action
        """
        if modalID == "deleteModalSubmit":
            self.batch_delete(pkList)
            self.success_message = 'SlateDocs successfully deleted!'

        if modalID == "csvModalSubmit":
            self.batch_csv_zip(pkList)
            self.success_message = 'SlateDocs successfully exported as a ZIP!'

        if modalID == "vantageModalSubmit":
            self.batch_csv_to_vantage(request, pkList)
            self.success_message = 'SlateDocs successfully sent to Vantage!'

        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


    def batch_delete(self, pkList):
        """
        Perform a soft delete for each pk in the pkList
        """
        for pk in pkList:
            slatedoc = SlateDoc.objects.get(id=pk)
            self.object = slatedoc
            slatedoc.soft_delete()
        return


    def batch_csv_zip(self, pkList):
        """
        Generate CSV for each PK and then return a ZIP archive of the data
        """
        t = time.time()
        datetime = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', time.localtime(t))

        csv_filepath = f"ngceng/static/docs/csv"
        zippath = f"ngceng/static/docs/zip"
        zipfilename = f"{datetime}_slatedoc_csv"

        os.mkdir(os.path.join(csv_filepath,datetime))

        for pk in pkList:
            item = SlateDoc.objects.get(pk=pk)
            slatedoc_resource = SlateDocResource()
            queryset = SlateDoc.objects.filter(pk=pk)
            dataset = slatedoc_resource.export(queryset)
            filename = item.filename
            filename_list = re.split('(\-+)|(\_+)', filename)
            filepath = f"ngceng/static/docs/csv/{datetime}/{filename_list[0]}.csv"

            with open(filepath, 'w', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerow(fieldnames_export)
                writer.writerows(dataset)
                f.close

        # csvfilelist = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(filepath)) if f.endswith(".csv")]

        csv_f = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(csv_filepath, datetime))
        zip_f = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(zippath, f"{zipfilename}.zip"))

        os.chdir(zippath)
        shutil.make_archive(zipfilename, 'zip', csv_f)
        
        # os.remove(csv_f)

        response = FileResponse(open(zip_f, 'rb').read())
        response['content_type'] = 'application/zip'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename = {zipfilename}.zip"
        response['input'] = input
        response['zipfilename'] = zipfilename

        return response
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('slatedoc-download', kwargs={'pks': ",".join(pkList)}))
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('slatedoc-download', kwargs={'file': f"{zipfilename}.zip"}))


    def batch_csv_to_vantage(self, request, pkList):
        """
        Generate a CSV file for each pk in the pk List, send these CSVs to Vantage. 
        """
        for pk in pkList:
            export_csv_to_vantage(request, pk)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Is your `batch_csv_zip` method definitely being called? The response is just not right?

Comment: @iain-shelvington - yes it’s def being called because the cSV files and the zip archive are created in the static file location. It’s just not getting returned in the response as a file download.